# how do I transfer it to the other list , If an array in a string is equal to the id of an object?

Tags: flutter

[image]

the string is coming like this, I want to add the objects if this objects id's are equal with this string array elements.

I am fetching the data,I convert it as model List  =>`List<DataDependantListModel> listModel;` 
I have tried to create condition but I couldn't. here is the class model ;

```
class DataDependantListModel {
String? id;
String? name;

DataDependantListModel({this.id, this.name});

DataDependantListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
id = json['Id'];
name = json['Name'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
data['Id'] = id;
data['Name'] = name;
return data;
}
}

 debugPrint("visafamilyId : " + visaFamilyId .toString());
      debugPrint("visa family contain : " + 
       visaFamilyId.contains("6").toString());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9glK.png)

Comment: show me your code and did you got this from your API?

Comment: Yes I got it from API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that's really strange if back-end return the response like that. It obviously should be a list, not a string. In my opinion, you have to ask back-end guys to change. Otherwise, you could do like this:

```
String strResponse = json["VisaFamilyId"] as String;
strResponse = strResponse.substring(1, strResponse.length - 1); // remove '[' and ']'
List<String> visaFamilyIds = strResponse.split(","); // every id is separated to each other by a comma
```

Well, now you get your list of ids, which are given by back-end. As your question, how to get list of `listModel` which have id in `visaFamilyIds`? You could code like this:

```
List<DataDependantListModel> result = listModel.map((e) => visaFamilyIds.contains(e.id)).toList();
```

By the way, please carefully check your `DataDependantListModel`. Are the fields **id** and **name** can be nullable? I don't think so.

Good luck.

Comment: I developed your idea's but I noticed that someting after first element of string that coming from database and after ',' there is space , how can I delete this space ?

Comment: Oops I didn't notice. Just replace "," -> ", "

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jsonDecode` from `dart:convert` to parse the `VisaFamilyId` (`"[6, 1003]"`) and then use `where` on `listModel` to filter out the common entries.

```dart
final visaFamilyId = jsonDecode('[1, 2]');
final result = listModel.where((e) => visaFamilyId.contains(e.id)).toList();
```

Comment: I edited my post I checked the value that you typed me with debugPrint(); it is viewing like this in debug console . result of this list is returning empty